# TransformedTargetRegressor for time series differencing

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series, regression

I want to do a time series/panel forecast using scikit-learns regression models (like proposed in https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/ ).

For stationarity and de-seasonalization, I need to differentiate my target variable:

```
y_trans = (y - y.shift(freq="1Y"))/y.shift(freq="1Y")
```

For evaluation I need the inverse transform of the predicted targets again:

```
y_predicted = y_trans_predicted * y.shift(freq="1Y") + y.shift(freq="1Y")
```

I thought about automating that in a pipeline using the TransformedTargetRegressor. However, I need the lags of the original y's for the inverse transformation. Therefore, I need to instantiate the TransformedTargetRegressor via the `transformer=` kw argument, using a custom transformer where I wrap the differentiation (`func=` with hardcoded y's is not viable because I want to do cross-validation). Problem is: if I do so, y will be converted to a np.array, and therefore `.shift()` and, even worse, matching rows by index will stop working.

Does someone know any workaround?

Thanks!